# application null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Previous Question:
May I know why this error will occur when I try to start RecyclerView activity doing a search from fragment.

After added adapter:

> error: OwnerDAO.getOwner()' on a null object reference

Fragment code:

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView;
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
  SearchAdapter adapter;
  OwnerDAO mOwnerDao;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    mOwnerDao = new OwnerDAO(getContext())
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(getContext(),mOwnerDao.getOwner());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

    return v;

   }
```

Search Adapter:

```
public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Owner> owners) {
    this.context = context;
    this.owners = owners;
}
```

Comment: With the given code, `adapter` is null, so no `Adapter` is actually attached to the `RecyclerView` when it gets laid out.

Comment: I did like this  adapter = new SearchAdapter(getContext(),mOwnerDao.getOwner()); but it seems can't get the database object

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it can't get the database object".

Comment: The error is (OwnerDAO.getOwner()' on a null object reference) when I clicked to start activity

Comment: It doesn't seem like that Exception would be coming from the code you have in your question.

Comment: Alright....It worked after I reinstall the application.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `layoutManager` after `setAdapter` like this :-

```
  recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

The error will be removed !!